# regex with variable number of whitespaces

Tags: javascript, regex

How can use javascript regex with a variable amount of whitespaces.
I have this situation where someone can make his own custom html template where pieces of text can be replaced with javascript variables.
The problem is the HTML, some can make a typo after <%= by typing more than one whitespace.

HTML:

```
<div>
    <%= someObjVar %>
</div>
```

How can I do a regexp with javascript that doesn't care about the number of whitespaces:

```
var json = {
        someObjVar : 'blah',
        someOtherObjVar : 'blah'
    }
  , re;

for (key in json) {
    re = new RegExp('<%= ' + json[key]+ ' %>',"g");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whitespaces should be around your string? Than:

```
'<%=\s*' + json[key]+ '\s*%>'
```